# Ember.js: Toggle Nested Views

Tags: ember.js

I have a header with some login/signup forms that popup when you click the respective buttons.

While it was working fine using just jQuery, I've now started to integrate Ember into the application and I'm running into some trouble with some simple toggle functionality.

Here's the basic HTML markup:

```
<header>
  <h1>Page Title<h1>

  <nav>
    <a id="toggles-login" class="button {{active_class_binding}}">Login</a>
    <a id="toggles-signup" class="button {{active_class_binding}}">Signup</a>
  </nav>

  <div id="popup-forms">
    <div id="login-form"></div>
    <div id="signup-form"></div>
  </div>
<header>
```

I'm completely new to Ember and I really have no idea how to set this up. The only thing I want is to be able to set the popup forms up as `Ember.View` objects and toggle them with some `action` helpers.

I really am lost on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to trigger simple actions to show the respective forms:

```
<a id="toggles-login" class="button {{active_class_binding}}" {{action showLoginForm target="view"}}>Login</a>
<a id="toggles-signup" class="button {{active_class_binding}}" {{action showSignupForm target="view"}}>Signup</a>
```

The corresponding view would have to implement both actions:

```
App.YourView = Ember.View.extend({
  showLoginForm : function(){
    this.$("#login-form").toggle();
  },
  showSignupForm : function(){
   this.$("#signup-form").toggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm really new to Ember and I'll probably be hitting up SO a lot with some Ember questions.